# Inserting multiple MySQL records using Python. ERROR: "Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type"

Tags: python, mysql

Inserting multiple MySQL records using Python
Error: Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

ERROR CODE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 181, in to_mysql
    return getattr(self, "_{0}_to_mysql".format(type_name))(value)
AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 432, in _process_params
    res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
  File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 432, in <listcomp>
    res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
  File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 184, in to_mysql
    "MySQL type".format(type_name))
TypeError: Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_mysql_2.py", line 22, in <module>
    my_cursor.execute(mike_placeholders,records_list)
  File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 557, in execute
    psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))
  File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 437, in _process_params
    "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

## Python Code:

```
#import sql.connector
import mysql.connector

#Create connection, added db we created#
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost', 
    user='root', 
    password='123', 
    database='testdb_1'
    ) 

#Create cursor for the connection
my_cursor = connection.cursor()

#Create SQL statement with placeholders and put in variable 
mike_placeholders="INSERT INTO users (name,email,age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) "

#Create list (array) of records
records_list = [('Tim','Tim@tim.com',32), ('Mary','Mary@mary.com',40), ('Sam','Sam@sam.com',50), ('Fred','Fred@fred.com',22) ]

#Execute cursor, requires SQl statement variable, record variable
my_cursor.execute(mike_placeholders,records_list)

#Commit the connection to make the change on the database
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 9):

Ahhh, I used the wrong Python term.

I should have used `executemany` when working with a `tuple`.

```
my_cursor.executemany(mike_placeholders,records_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass a list to `my_cursor.execute()`, you need to iterate over the list:

```
for values in records_list:
    my_cursor.execute(mike_placeholders, values)
```

Or you could repeat the `(%s, %s, %s)` multiple times and do it all in a single query by flattening the list of tuples.

```
mike_placeholders="INSERT INTO users (name,email,age) VALUES " + ", ".join(["(%s, %s, %s)"] * len(records_list))
my_cursor.execute(mike_placeholders, sum(records_list))
```

Comment: @Barmar You are fantastic. This solution worked for me after searching the solution for hours. I upvoted it.

Comment: The answers that use `executemany()` are better.

Answer (score 3):

```
use my_cursor.executemany(mike_placeholders,records_list)
```

If you have **multiple elements** which are saved in a **list** or **tuple** then use,

```
cursor.executemany(query,list) or cursor.executemany(query,tuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use a for loop and INSERT item by item

```
for x in records_list:
    my_cursor.execute(mike_placeholders, x)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.